# Aggregate data and migrate them to another database

Tags: mysql, talend

I'm new to Talend. I want to make a script that transform my data (using an sql query) from a database and insert them to an other one.

Could you help me please with the list of components that I should use ? any tutorial ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Talend has many database specific components. You will find input and output components for all databases. input components are those which enables you to read data from database and bring it to talend and output components are those which allows you to write/insert data to database.

for example if your source and target are both oracle then - 
toracleinput will be for reading from oracle db - (you have to mention connection details, sql query and schema for this component).
toracleoutput will be for inserting this data back to oracle database table. Here again you have to mention connection details, target table name, type of operation etc..

finally you have to connect flow of data from input to output component and if you need any intermediate transformations, joins etc you have to user other talend components in between like tMap etc..